# 3 foreign keys to one table to one column

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

there are 2 entities: "A" and "B".
[image]
In essence, "A" there are fields:

```
 - A_id (PK)
 - B1_id (FK)
 - B2_id (FK)
 - B3_id (FK)
```

In essence, "B": B_id and other fields. Is it possible to make relationships to the EF and MS one to one, where "B1_id", "B2_id" and "B3_id" are external keys to one property B_id in table "B". If it is possible, then how can I name the navigation properties in class "A", I think there should be three?

Comment: What is the cardinality? Are they one-to-one or one-to-many?  If the latter, you must build an intersection table. Why are there multiple columns in one table all referencing one column in another? Also, I don't think you can do FK from integer to binary - I'm not sure if that was a typo.

Comment: Aside from the previously mentioned datatype issues this sounds like a questionable design. But hard to say for sure because this has been anonymized for posting.

Comment: Aside from the data type mismatch, and the possibility that a junction table may be a better structure, you can't create multiple foreign keys from one table to another, with declarative referential integrity, in SQL Server.  You can in Postgres and even SQLite, in case those are feasible alternatives for you.

Comment: 1. It was a typo, the B_id column for table "B" should be of Int type
2. The meaning of this connection is that table "B" stores images, and table "A" stores 3 references to various images in table "B". So this is a one-to-one relationship
3. I'm not sure, but I also thought that this is an example of a bad design. If you have suggestions, I'd like to see a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //another properties

    public virtual B B1 { get; set; }
    public int B1Id { get; set; }

    public virtual B B2 { get; set; }
    public int B2Id { get; set; }

    public virtual B B3 { get; set; }
    public int B3Id { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //another properties

    [InverseProperty(B1)]
    public virtual ICollection<A> A1 { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(B2)]
    public virtual ICollection<A> A2 { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(B3)]
    public virtual ICollection<A> A3 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
 public class A
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int B1Id { get; set; }
        public int B2Id { get; set; }
        public int B3Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("B1Id")]
        public B B1 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("B2Id")]
        public B B2 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("B3Id")]
        public B B3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```